# Flutter error 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart'

Tags: ios, flutter

A few days ago I created a new project and it was progressing smoothly. My project broke down while I was trying something new tonight.

When I couldn't solve it, I wanted to create it from scratch and move it there, but while moving, I realized that there was a problem with the packages I added.
These are all the packages in my project that worked fine yesterday.

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  line_awesome_flutter: ^2.0.0
  delayed_display: ^2.0.0
  flutter_bounce: ^1.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
  swipe: ^0.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/onboard/
    - assets/images/
```

When I add the **shared_preferences: ^2.0.6** package, the 'generated_plugin_registrant.dart' page is created and the 'import '**package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart'**;' glows red.

At the same time, when I say run in the google fonts package, it gives an error on ios.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
    [!] Failed to load 'shared_preferences' podspec: 
    [!] Invalid `shared_preferences.podspec` file: undefined method `HomeFrame=' for #<Pod::Specification name="shared_preferences">
    Did you mean?  homepage=.

     #  from /Users/thekavak/Desktop/clotie/clotie/ios/.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios/shared_preferences.podspec:11
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #                         DESC
     >    s.HomeFrame         = 'https://github.com/flutter/plugins'
     #    s.license          = { :type => 'BSD', :file => '../LICENSE' }
     #  -------------------------------------------

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:175:in `rescue in store_podspec'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:161:in `store_podspec'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:17:in `block in fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:989:in `fetch_external_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:968:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:966:in `fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-user-defined-build-types-0.0.7/lib/cocoapods-user-defined-build-types/private_api_hooks.rb:94:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-user-defined-build-types-0.0.7/lib/cocoapods-user-defined-build-types/private_api_hooks.rb:94:in `block in <class:Installer>'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

All this happened in the new empty project, I just added the packages and it started giving errors without writing anything to the main file.

All I can think of is that back in the day I had a page in an old project called HomeFrame.dart, could this have broken something? How can I fix this? I will be grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an M1 Mac, you can solve the problem like this. Move to `/ios`, open terminal, and run the following commands:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi  
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```